# Where can I find the rosfusion.py tool?

Tags: ros, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear ROS community,

I'm new on ROS, and I'm following the "How to cross-compile any ROS package for Android" tutorial, and everything is ok until the step that I have to add the contents of the file `robot_localization.rosinstall` generated to the `ndk.rosinstall`.

I'm trying to find the tool called `rosfusion.py` because when I execute the command line

```
./rosfusion.py -n robot_localization.rosinstall -t ndk.rosinstall
```

it doesn't work. This is what I get from the terminal

```
~/ros-android-ndk/roscpp_android$ ./rosfusion.py -n robot_localization.rosinstall -t ndk.rosinstall
bash: ./rosfusion.py: No such file or directory
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/218623/where-can-i-find-the-rosfusion.py-tool?/) by [daniel6omez](https://answers.ros.org/users/24241/daniel6omez/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-10-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-10-05**:
I can't find that file anywhere, so I suggest that you open an issue on the [issue tracker](https://github.com/creativa77/roscpp_android/issues) of the `roscpp_android` package.

**Comment by [Gary Servin](https://answers.ros.org/users/10481/gary-servin/) on 2015-10-13**:
Sorry for this, already created an issue on the repo and will fix it ASAP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The issue has been solved. Please update your repo with the file that was missing. Sorry for the inconvenience.
https://github.com/creativa77/roscpp_android/issues/30

---

Originally posted by [Ernesto Corbellini](https://answers.ros.org/users/23887/ernesto-corbellini/) with karma: 101 on 2015-10-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1